# Custom Protocol in Firefox WebExtensions

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, custom-protocol

I have a old addons to Firefox that registry a custom protocol "linkpassword://"

Since Firefox Version 57 the addon stop working and I have to rewrite the full addons as a Firefox WebExtenstion.

My issue is I can't find a way to registry a handler for protocol "linkpassword://".

Answer (score 2):

The "protocol_handlers" section in the manifest.json of your Firefox WebExtensions can be used to register a common or a custom protocol handler.

But from the documentation at [MDN WebExtensions protocol_handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/protocol_handlers) it seems like you have to prefix a custom protocol handler with *web+something* or *ext+something*.

You can process the link in your extension by just using a page in your extension as "uriTemplate" like this:

```
"protocol_handlers": [
    {
        "protocol"   : "ext+linkpassword",
        "name"       : "Password Link",
        "uriTemplate": "html/processLink.html#login=%s"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't register a handler for `linkpassword://` with WebExtensions.

As for now only the specified whitelisted protocols are allowed to be used without a prefix (one of `bitcoin`,  `geo`, `gopher`, `im`, `irc`, `ircs`, `magnet`, `mailto`, `mms`, `news`, `nntp`, `sip`, `sms`, `smsto`, `ssh`, `tel`, `urn`, `webcal`, `wtai`, `xmpp`). Any other custom name requires to be prefixed with either `web+` or `ext+`. See [protocol_handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/protocol_handlers) reference.

With the prefix you can register it this way:

```
"protocol_handlers": [
    {
        "protocol"   : "ext+linkpassword",
        "name"       : "Password Link",
        "uriTemplate": "html/processLink.html#login=%s"
    }
],
```

Then you'll have to use `ext+linkpassword://` in your links to trigger the handler.

While with the current state of WebExtensions you can't set a handler for an arbitrary protocol, like `linkpassword://`, it is likely to change at some point, since there are [some discussions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271553) about it, but it's hard to say when to expect this. As a temporary workaround before the real solution is available you can patch `linkpassword://` to `ext+linkpassword://` on the web page with your WebExtension JS code so that the handler is still triggered even if the links on the page were loaded with the `linkpassword://` schema.